# Dart ways of handling Futures

Tags: dart

I saw a Dart screencast about `Futures` and how to handle them. It said there are two ways of handling some `Futures` that mixed with sync code. This is the example code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Map sanitizeParams(Map p) {/*.....*/}
Future sendToServer(Map p) {/*.....*/}

Future sendParams(Map params) => sendToServer(sanitizeParams(params));
```

Above is the less preferred way, and here is the code that is better (according to the one who made the screencast) :

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Map sanitizeParams(Map p) {/*.....*/}
Future sendToServer(Map p) {/*.....*/}

Future sendParams(Map params) => 
  new Future.value(params)
    .then(sanitizeParams)
    .then(sendToServer);
```

Why is the second one preferred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First reason is readability: `sanitizeParams` needs to happen before `sendToServer` but it reads in different order, which is preferably avoided when working with futures.

The more important reason is that if `sanitizeParams` throws an exception then `sendParams` won't return a future but throw instead, and this makes it harder to compose it with other futures. The second example avoids this by first making the arguments available as Future (`Future.value`) and then chaining other functions on that.

IIRC, this is explained in the screencast.

Comment: I would say the error handling is the one and only reason to use the latter. Readability is arguable as always.

Comment: +1 @KaiSellgren I agree - that was exactly my reaction when I was watching the screencast, but I didn't want to go too much into that